# How do you save data for two text fields using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

How do you save data for two text fields using NSUserDefaults on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:FirstTextView];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:SecondTextView];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

For load:

```
NSDate *textfield1Date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:FirstTextView];
NSDate *textfield2Date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SecondTextView];
```